# jQuery prependTo() – duplicated element

Tags: jquery, prepend

I have this code:

```
<div class="someClass">
    <a href="#" class="link">Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="link"><span class="selected">Text</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Text</a>
</div>
```

When I what to move link where is `span` with class `selected` to first position, I do:

```
$('.selected').parent().prependTo('.someClass');
```

But then I get something like this, element is duplicated:

```
<div class="someClass">
    <a href="#" class="link"><span class="selected">Text</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link"><span class="selected">Text</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Text</a>
</div>
```

Where is the problem?
Thank you for any advice!

Comment: shouldn't be duplicated, jsfiddle link for having the problem???

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/ec16qv32/ Do you have more than one `.selected` element in your document?

Answer (score 0):

Now I get it. I'm using JavaScript for mobile navigation. Something like this:

```
<div class="mobileNavigation">
    <div class="js-cloneElement" data-sourceSelector=".someClass"></div>
</div>
```

So that's the reason for duplicated element!